# how to set a list of images next to eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images but i want all the images next to each other. and than with horizontal scroll.

I tried to set a max height for the scroll menu but that his hide the 2 images below. I also disabled vertical scroll but that doesn't work to.

If it is possible I want only use css. if I need javascript to fix it I use Jquery.

[image: What I have now]

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/4.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/5.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/6.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/7.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/8.jpg" class="img">
    </div>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/image.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
body{
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 overflow-y:hidden;
}
.img{
 height:100px;
 width:200px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:0px;
}

.loaded{
 width:100%;
}
#list{
 overflow-y:hidden;
 width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add

```
  white-space: nowrap;
```

to `#list`

Since your `.img` images are correctly set to `inline-block` you can now control the parent element's whitespace with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space (which applies to the inner *inline*, *inline-block* children.)

> nowrap
>       Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.

Comment: Don't forget the crossbrowser inline block solution display:-moz-inline-stack;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;

Answer (score 2):

As @roko-c-buljan said simply add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `#list`. This suppresses line-breaks in the text, which the images are as they have `display: inline-block`.

```css
body{
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 overflow-y:hidden;
}
.img{
 height:100px;
 width:200px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:0px;
}

.loaded{
 width:100%;
}
#list{
 overflow-y:hidden;
 width:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/4.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/5.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/6.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/7.jpg" class="img">
        <img src="img/8.jpg" class="img">
    </div>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/image.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://codepen.io/kozumii/pen/IoAFb

```
#list{
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're familiar with floats,you can add

```
#list img {
  float:left;
}
```