# div that has different height display in a awful position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3, I have this html structure where each `.col-md-2` div container has different size of contents so they have different height but same width and so when not equal height div look is a awful position (big spaces between element).

How to make it like a fluid grid layout that remove spaces between each `.col-md-2` and it display clean and align even they have different height?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `white-space: nowrap;` or `float left;` add one of these as css to each of your `col-md-2`

Comment: no luck. still the same

Comment: can you add the css code if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699589/how-to-set-a-list-of-images-next-to-eachother , I have asked before a question about a white space between `inline-block` placed images. Take a look at the first answer

Comment: refer to this link http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: please add a bootply to help us out...

Comment: solved. I tried different approach, thank you